# Accessing app configurations in middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do you access application configuration settings inside a middleware function with express? For example say I have the following contrived example which is defined it's own module and I want to branch based on the results of a application configuration.

```
function fail(req, res, next) {  
    if (app.config.fail === true) {
        res.json({'err': 'failed'});
    }
    return next();
}
```

What is correct way to handle this with express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you wanna access `app` inside a middleware you can do that with `req.app`.  As explained [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.app)

I hope this is what you were looking for!